# How to handle figure overlapping in Graphiti?

Tags: raphael, draw2d, graphiti-js

I have a big rectangle and a small rectangle made of graphiti, now when I drag small rectangle over big rectangle then I am not able to select that small rectangle instead big rectangle got selected.

In short that small rectangle doesn't has mouse event until it is on big rectangle.

So is there any way when we drag any figure1 over other figure2, then figure1 should be draggable instead of figure2.

I have remove all selectable properties and draggable properties from big rectangle ( figure2 ) but its not working.Please help me for the same as it is very important.
Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

selecting overlapping figures is not implementd at the moment. This is an open issue.
Graphiti implements a simple hit test. Fist bounding box hit wins.

Comment: Thanks Andreas but how can i get this new version? Please provide me details I want this new Graphti version.